# How make a quiet cp in jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins

I copy several files in my Jenkins job, and that verbose output is not useful, I want a quiet cp, in the Job console output, I already try to cp to >> /dev/null but did not work...

Comment: is this in a shell command? by default, cp is not verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
set +x
cp /source/files /dest/
set -x
```

By default Jenkins executes shell step with -xe flags so all commands are printed before execution and in case of error code of any command the job will fail. +x should suppress the output of cp.

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can put all your `cp` command in a single shell/python/ruby executable file. and then only execute that file from jenkins `Execute Shell` job step.